# Angular change detection - recreation of components

Tags: angular

So i read a lot about angular change detection, i understand what triggers change detection and i think i understand that whenever change detected ngOnChanges is called, and i understand ngOnInit should be called once and ever since the component should be reused in every change. but I get to see a lot of ngOnInit calls on my components, and it kills the performance of the angular app so:

Apart for real first time showing of a component, what else could trigger Angular to dump the old component and create a new component? (e.g new lifecycle starts ->...-> ngOnInit)

Would appriciate tips on how to avoid that and pitfalls i should be aware of in this regard.

Thanks!

Comment: *ngIf that component on parent container into/out of view

Comment: *ngIf that component **or** parent container into/out of view

Comment: You'd get better answers if you'd tell us more about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The ngOnInit lifecycle hook is called once for each component/directive instance.

So it is not possible to have mutliple ngOnInit calls for the same instance of a component.

Using structural directives like *ngIf/*ngFor you are actually destroying and creating instances of a specific component and for this reason you will see multiple ngOnInit calls for the same component, but the instance of the component is not the same.

In a good organized angular application this is not affecting the preformances, you are probably doing something wrong